# python 3 List object assignment to dictionary error

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

i've got the following issue:
Python assigning empty lists to my dictionary even the list contains elements. The list is stored in a variable, but if i provide the values manually, it assigns given values to the dictionary properly

i've tested to provides the values manually (worked), create a new dictionary and assigning the list from variable (not worked)

```
valueable_data = list()
output_data3 = dict()
for k,v in output_data.items():
    valueable_data.clear()  #emptying the list

    for list in input_data[1:]:
        for element in list:
            if list.index(element) == int(v) and element != '':
                print(element)
                valueable_data.append(element.replace("'",""))
                #print(valeuable_data) 
    if len(valueable_data) != 0:
        print(len(valueable_data))  #19 elements
        print(type(valueable_data))  #<class> 'list'
        output_data3[k] = valueable_data
        #valeuable_data.clear()

for k,v in output_data3.items():
    print(len(v))  #result []
```

The desired output would be something like this:

letters ('a','b','c')

numbers ('1','2','3')

if i do the determination this way:

```
output_data3[k] = ('a','b','c')
```

the result is (as desired):

```
k ('a','b','c')
```

thank you for helping me out!

Comment: Because you are clearing your list, and assigning the same list to different values in the dict.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could show us what `input_data` and `output_data` look like, or give us a representative examples.